# SAML 2 redirect to login page

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, security, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

hi i am building a saml sso Idp Using ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 and Asp.net core Mvc,
i am using a cookies based authentification.
i want to to wen the sp send the saml auth request the idp redirect to the login page and after the verification of credential information the user redirect back to his sp with the saml response.

how can i Handle user login e.g. in GUI to redirect the user to login page ?

this is the saml login method :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
        {
            bool isSamlRequest = HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey("SAMLRequest")
            || HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("SAMLRequest");

            if(!isSamlRequest)
                return RedirectToAction(actionName:"login",controllerName: "Account");
            
            var requestBinding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
            var relyingParty = await ValidateRelyingParty(ReadRelyingPartyFromLoginRequest(requestBinding));

            var saml2AuthnRequest = new Saml2AuthnRequest(GetRpSaml2Configuration(relyingParty));
            try
            {
                requestBinding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnRequest);

                // ****  Handle user login e.g. in GUI ****
                // Test user with session index and claims
                var sessionIndex = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var claims = CreateTestUserClaims(saml2AuthnRequest.Subject?.NameID?.ID);

                return LoginResponse(saml2AuthnRequest.Id, Saml2StatusCodes.Success, requestBinding.RelayState, relyingParty, sessionIndex, claims);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return LoginResponse(saml2AuthnRequest.Id, Saml2StatusCodes.Responder, requestBinding.RelayState, relyingParty);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a rather big deal to implement user login securely, and there is not a simple answer I’m afraid.

It is better to use an IdP out of the box, you can use [FoxIDs](https://www.foxids.com) for free. It is open-source and can be deployed in you own Azure tenant.

Answer (score 0):

you can  check in saml login method if the user not login it will redirect to login page with the saml request and after in the login page send the username and password and saml request to the authenticate method, after validation of user credential redirect to the saml login method with the samlrequest.